# MySql converts a floating value into integer when recording on a float field on DDBB

Tags: php, mysql

I have this UPDATE query:

```
 UPDATE ws_users SET us_credits='251181.5' WHERE us_id=2;
```

The `us_credits` field, as you can see is a floating field with a default value of zero:

[image: im]

Every UPDATE query trying to set a floating value to `us_credits` results on an integer, for example, the query first typed results on a **251182** record on this field.

If I try to make a manual change to the record as seen above, it neither records the floating value, just integer (**251184** in this case):

[image: img]

Comment: `float(m,n)` you need to define the column accordingly not just `float`

Comment: The only column type I have similar to your explanatin is decimal(m,n), and it does neither accept decimals on the records. I still have the same problem, and when I try to change it manually an error emerges: data truncated for column ws_credits at row 1

Comment: Ok worked, after setting (10,1) on the lenght. could you post this as an answer in order to tick you? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE
>   PRECISION(M,D). Here, “(M,D)” means than values can be stored with up
>   to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal
>   point.For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 
>   when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you
>   insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is
>   999.0001.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html

So you need to define the column for handing the decimal points also.